# An uncertain issue about CPU cache or GC or any else

Tags: json, memory, go, garbage-collection, cpu

I'm writing a arbitrary JSON parser for golang, the project nearly finished. But I found a confusing problem about the performance:

I want to test the performance about parse a big(100Mb) JSON string, I use the test file itself to init the JSON struct in memory and write the marshaled JSON string to a file, and then read from it, if the file exists already, will not init it in memory, just read from file directly. The performance is totally different: cost about double time to parse when read from file directly. At the same time, I'm testing the performance about parse normal(1Kb) JSON string and deep(2Mb) JSON string, both of these are almost unaffected.

Why? is CPU cache? or GC? or any else?

The code at https://github.com/acrazing/cheapjson, and I opened a issue about this problem at https://github.com/acrazing/cheapjson/issues/1. You can get more detailed information about the benchmark from here.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @peterSO Could you tell me how you do the test?

Answer (score 0):

This is the old benchmark result, time is at 11:01

[image]

This is the final test result currently, the result could not reproduce, it's amazing.

[image]